# how to insert multiple textbox value into richtextbox in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, textbox

I have one textbox1 and one richtextbox1.
when user click the "enter" button the textbox1 data should display in the richtextbox1.
if the user enter another new data in the textbox1, it should be displayed in richtextbox1 in next row
but previous address shouldn't be erased in the richtextbox1. it should remain there.
all data  here is string type.

if anyone can give me the solution it will be great.

Comment: This is basic string concatenation, what have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
RichTextBox1.AppendText(TextBox1.Text & Environment.NewLine)
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @X-Istence !!! what u talking about!!! the man said it worked how come is not provide an answer to the question??